# How does dbms maintain atomicity during transactions?

Tags: database, transactions, atomic, acid

I was reading about ACID properties of dbms of which 1 property is **Atomicity**.

http://ecomputernotes.com/database-system/rdbms/transaction

**Scenario:**

Suppose that, just prior to execution of transaction Ti the values of account A and B are Rs.I000 and Rs.2000.

Now, suppose that during the execution of Ti, a power failure has occurred that prevented the Ti to complete successfully. The point of failure may be after the completion Write (A,a) and before Write(B,b). It means that the changes in A are performed but not in B. Thus the values of account A and Bare Rs.950 and Rs.2000 respectively. We have lost Rs.50 as a result 'of this failure.

**Now, our database is in inconsistent state.**

My question is in case of power failure which lead us to the inconsistent state, how does we recover from it?

Can we do it at application level/ code level?

How many ways are there to recover from it?

Comment: Are you asking about some specific database, or in general? Cause these ways and algorithms may differ from one vendor to another.

Comment: In general, dont want to know about algorithms. For example: Q is if there is a power failure and amount is deducted from 1 account, how could they bring it back to consistent state i.e. depositing amount in account 2.?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, these ways may differ from one database to another, but usually DBMSs insure atomicity this way:

When a new request for data change is received, a database first writes this request to a special log which represents a *change vector*. Only when this record has been successfully written, a transaction can be committed.

In case of power failure this log persists. And database can recover from inconsistent state using this log, applying the changes one by one.

For example, this log in Oracle database is called [Redo Log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo001.htm#ADMIN11302). In PostgreSql it's called [WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/wal-intro.html).